# Using Rank() in SQL to rank groups

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rank

Here is an SQL query (in the Google BigQuery environment using one of their demo datasets, but this is a standard SQL question):

```
SELECT name, sum(number) as namecount, RANK(name) 
OVER (ORDER BY decade, namecount DESC) as PLACEMENT,

case 
when year >= 1940 and year <= 1949 then '40s' 
when year >= 1950 and year <= 1959 then '50s'
when year >= 1960 and year <= 1969 then '60s'
when year >= 1970 and year <= 1979 then '70s'
when year >= 1980 and year <= 1989 then '80s'
when year >= 1990 and year <= 1999 then '90s'
when year >= 2000 and year <= 2014 then 'Nowish'
else
    'other'
end   as  DECADE

FROM [bigquery-public-data:usa_names.usa_1910_2013]  
where gender = 'F' and year > 1939   
group by decade, name
having namecount > 25000
order by decade, namecount DESC 

limit 1000000
```

Let's say I am interested in knowing the rank for **Linda** for each decade.  Thus, I would like the query to tell me Linda is ranked 2nd in the 1940s and Linda is ranked 2nd in the 1950s.  However the rank order is absolute in the given query, thus Linda is 118th in 1950s (Mary is the leader in the 1950s at 117th).

A snippet of the result set:

```
name    namecount Placement Decade

Mary    639971      1       40s  
Linda   531587      2       40s 
[ ... ]
Mary    625464    117       50s
Linda   564204    118       50s
```

How to reset the rank so that Mary shows up as #1 for the 1950s and Linda shows up as #2, and to reset the ranks in a similar manner for each subsequent decade?

Comment: SQL Server <> Big Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mihai's answer is almost right.

```
SELECT name, sum(number) as namecount, RANK(name) 
OVER (PARTITION BY decade ORDER BY namecount DESC) as PLACEMENT,
....
```

I suspect it would work but ordering by columns in your partitioning criteria is redundant.

As a side note, which is the major reason for this post, is that the `order by namecount` is not something I would expect to work in most relational databases because it is the result of an aggregate itself.  So it is nice for your case that your database supports it, but don't count on it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  This gave me a Placement of 1 for every row, but it gave me the syntax to arrive at what I needed, which turned out to be:     SELECT name, sum(number) as namecount, RANK(name) 
OVER (PARTITION BY decade order by namecount DESC) as PLACEMENT,

Comment: yeah, sorry.  of course name should not be part of the partition criteria. :-P

Comment: fixed it.  I am still surprised that SQL Server lets you reference aggregates in the window :-)

Comment: I guess referencing an aggregate is a nuance of "Legacy SQL", the almost-SQL that I'm running in the Google BigQuery environment.

Answer (score 1):

Partition it also in the RANK clause

```
SELECT name, sum(number) as namecount, RANK(name) 
OVER (PARTITION BY decade, name ORDER BY decade, namecount DESC) as PLACEMENT,
....
```